# How to delete the Jenkins Upstream/Downstream dependency

Tags: jenkins, hudson

Actually i have a project **foo parent**, which was suppose to trigger **foo child** , as it is configured through the option.

> Build other projects

But it also triggering the **bar child**.

Even if I unchecked the option

> Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built

, but **foo-parent** is still triggering **foo-child** as well as **bar-child**.

Any suggestion on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you unchecked "Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built" in all three jobs. Can you also check if you go to bar-child job, is there any upstream job shown there. It may be triggered from child job.

Comment: I have unchecked the option already. Also, inside the bar-child dashboard, foo-parent is showing as upstream job along with bar-parent. 
I am not able to figure out, from where the relationship is coming for foo-parent and bar-child.

Comment: Sry about the late reply. I need to do the same for all the parent-child jobs and then it worked.  Thanks :)